# Upload File using selenium on Pyhon (IE only)

Tags: python, selenium, file-upload, upload

I am using the code below to upload a file using selenium driving Microsoft IE.
But i am unable to send_keys to the file input. the code below however opens up the browse file window (this only happens in IE, not firefox)

Is there a way using **only IE**, where  I can send_keys to the html input or on a worst case scenario where I can send_keys to the Pop up browse window and then click on open?

**html code:**

```
<TR>
<TD class="label">File Name:</TD>
<TD id="tagFile"><INPUT size=30 TYPE="file" NAME="fileName"></TD>
</TR>   
<TR>
```

**html screenshot:**

[image]

**Browse screenshot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img[alt=\"Add Document\"]").click()
driver.find_element_by_name("title").send_keys("PCA Documentation")
driver.find_element_by_name("issueNo").send_keys("1")
print destination

file_input = driver.find_element_by_name("fileName")    
#driver.file_input.send_keys(destination)   
driver.file_input.send_keys("C:\\installAgent.log")                                     
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img[alt=\"Upload my file\"]").click()
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be just `file_input.send_keys("C:\\installAgent.log")` instead of `driver.file_input.send_keys("C:\\installAgent.log")`?

Comment: I had eventually figured it out and used driver.find_element_by_name("fileName").send_keys(destination)

Comment: this can be the answer, pls submit your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be just `file_input.send_keys("C:\\installAgent.log")` instead of `driver.file_input.send_keys("C:\\installAgent.log")`